# What values of $b$ such that $f_n(x)=b\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

For what values of $b$ does the sequence of functions:

for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let

$$f_n(x)=b\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right), \text{ } x\in[0,1]$$

converge uniformly in the space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the supremum metric $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$$

**My working and my doubts:**

I claim that the sequence $g_n(x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly to $g(x)=1$ on $x\in[0,1]$.

For any $\epsilon>0$, we need to show there is an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ implies $d(g_n,g)<\epsilon$.

As we know as $n\to\infty$, $\frac{x}{n}\to0$ and $\cos(\frac{x}{n})\to1$. And the convergence is independent of the $x$, as long as $x\in[0,1]$.

**1. What got me stuck is the explicit value of $N$. I am not sure how to find an explicit value of $N$ for each $\epsilon$.**

**2. After we have shown that $g_n(x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly, can we just say that $b\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ will still converge regardless of the value of $b$?**

**3. So is it correct that the solution to the original question is for all value of $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $f_n$ converges uniformly?**

Helps are greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, note that $ \cos(x)$ is positive and decreasing for $x \in[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.
So $f_n(x)$ is also positive and decreasing on $[0,1]$, thus we have 
$$d(1,f_n) = \sup_{x \in[0,1]} 1 - \cos \left( \frac{x}{n} \right) = 1 - \cos \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$$
So you are left to show that $\cos \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, which follows from the continuity of $\cos(x)$ in $0$.

Then if you multiply with $b$, the same trick holds for positive $b$, and for negative $b$ you must be careful with the sign, but the trick still holds.

So yes, $f_n$ converges uniform for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for an explicit bound in (1):
$$\forall x\in\Bbb R:\ 1-\frac{x^2}2\le\cos x\le 1.$$

(2): Yes, because $|b\cos(x/n)-b| = |b|\,|\cos(x/n)-1|$.

(3): Yes.